# Java Team development environment

Tags: java, project-management, eclipse, subversion

I am looking to set up a development environment (ideally that works with MyEclipse+Java+Tomcat) which can be used to control sharing of code updates better than our current SVN repository. Ideally the environment should send automated notifications when code changes are committed and auto prepare a .war file for deployment to a test server (maybe need to prepare some script here?).

Reverting changes should be transparent and straight forward.

Any recommendations please?

Comment: Can you specify the term "environment" in this context? From your requirements, that should be possible with what you have (SVN, using commit-hooks), or might be improved replacing SVN by Git. But neither Git nor SVN are called "environments", so I would guess there's more to it?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: @Izzy you're right sorry. I need an extension to my current environment that does not simply allow you to commit and checkout code but sends all users updates when code has been committed/checked in and can prepare wars for deploying to a test environment. Our current system allows code checkin and checkout but does not notifiy you or do automatic deploys

Comment: Have you looked into post-commit-hooks? Those are basically scripts fired whenever a commit is done. So you could use those to build `*.war` files, and send notes to the others to "update". With Git, similar hooks do exist (I'd recommend using the "push" event here, as "commit" is only local with Git) – and I e.g. make much use of them at Github. But for an exact "howto", SR is not the correct place.

Comment: Thank you for your help and comments. I got the answers I was looking for :)